# CAS: avoid that a user authenticates more than once

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, cas

Is there a way to avoid that a user can authenticate more than once on CAS?
My configuration uses Hazelcast to share tickets between two nodes of a cluster.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported and it would be a rather expensive feature because you need to look into hazelcast to find all tickets with the matching userid and then block if you find more than 1. The query may very likely timeout.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I implemented a workaround logging the login event on a database table (username + login time). When the user tries to login, I first check if there's a row in such a table. If it's present, I reject the login. The row is deleted when the user logs out or the ticket expires. Do you see any drawback?

Comment: Note that it looks like the cas 5.2 release has added support for this.